# dismiss bootstrap3 modal on click event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular2-template

I have an angular2 project and I am using bootstrap3 modal in it. My modal has some dynamic data in it. Now when I open that modal and click outside of the modal, the modal get dismiss. And if again open that modal, the modal opens and i can see my data in it very well.

But when I click on the close button on modal, which has (data-dismiss=modal), the modal get closed and if I again open that modal, the modal opens but there is no data present on it.

So i want a close button on modal, and same functionality like when I click on modal, the modal get dismiss but if I again open that modal, my data should be present in that modal.(same as clicking outside the modal).

Please help me out...

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share some code or if you can create a jsfiddle will be very helpful.

Comment: This is simple bootstrap3 modal. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

use **?** for safe navigation(Once your data will come from API then it will load on model).

exp. **in html part.**

```
<p>{{user?.name}}</p>
```

Comment: No my issue is closing the modal. Data is not coming from the API, there is a for loop in the modal, which generates the data. I want that whatever CSS close the modal on outside clicking on modal, the same CSS on button click on modal.

Comment: then you can use the elementRef of angular2